# Doctrine 2 - persist error - Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I create such entries in DOctrine. I'm trying to add basket to page . 
This is my entities:
My Entities:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Page")
 * @Table(name="page")

 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", name="p_id")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $p_id;
    /** @Column(type="string", name="p_title") */
    private $p_title;
    /** @Column(type="datetime", name="p_created") */
    private $p_created_at;
    /** @Column(type="datetime", name="p_updated_at") */
    private $p_updated_at;
    /** @Column(type="text", name="p_abstract") */
    private $p_abstract;
     /** @Column(type="text", name="p_fulltext", nullable=false) */
    private $p_fulltext;
     /** @Column(type="string", name="p_author", nullable=true) */
    private $p_author;
     /** @Column(type="string", name="p_url",nullable=true) */
    private $p_url;
     /** @Column(type="string", name="p_meta_title",nullable=true) */
    private $p_meta_title;
     /** @Column(type="string", name="p_meta_keywords",nullable=true) */
    private $p_meta_keywords;
     /** @Column(type="string", name="p_meta_description",nullable=true) */
    private $p_meta_description;
      /** @Column(type="string", name="p_status") */
    private $p_status;
    /** @Column(type="string", name="p_weight") */
    private $p_weight; 
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="pages")
     * @JoinColumn(name="p_u_id", referencedColumnName="u_id")
    */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Page\Basket", mappedBy="page", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $pageBaskets;


    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->pageBaskets = new ArrayCollection();
       $this->pageMedia = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->property;
    }
    public function __set($property,$value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
    public function getPageMedia()
    {
        return $this->pageMedia;
    }
    public function setUser(\App\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function getMedias()
    {
       return $this->pageMedia;
    }
    public function getPageBaskets()
    {
        return $this->pageBaskets;
    }
    /**
     * Set Page Values
     * @var array $values
     */
    public function setPageProperties(array $values)
    {
        $this->p_updated_at =  new \DateTime("now");
        $this->p_title = $values['p_title'];
        $this->p_abstract = $values['p_abstract'];
        $this->p_meta_title = $values['p_meta_title'];
        $this->p_meta_keywords = $values['p_meta_keywords'];
        $this->p_meta_description = $values['p_meta_description'];
        $this->p_url = $values['p_url'];
        $this->p_fulltext = $values['p_abstract'];
        $this->p_author = '';
        $this->p_status = 1;

    }
    public function getSimpleValues()
    {
        return array(
            'p_updated_at' =>  $this->p_updated_at,
            'p_title' => $this->p_title,
            'p_abstract' =>  $this->p_abstract,
            'p_meta_title' => $this->p_meta_title,
            'p_meta_keywords' => $this->p_meta_keywords,
            'p_meta_description' => $this->p_meta_description,
            'p_url' => $this->p_url,
            'p_fulltext' =>  $this->p_fulltext,
            'p_author' => $this->p_author
        );
    }
}

?>


<?php
namespace App\Entity\Page;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="page_basket")

 */
class Basket
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", name="pb_id")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $pb_id;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Page", )
     * @JoinColumn(name="pb_id", referencedColumnName="p_id")
    */
    private $page;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->property;
    }
    public function __set($property,$value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
    public function setPage($page)
    {
        $this->page = $oszpage;
    }
}

?>
```

But where are doing such stuff:

```
 $page->getPageBaskets()->add($basket);
```

Im getting :
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Having same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780016/spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-null-given) except that I already get an error when I try to retrieve the main entity! Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Best to follow the examples in the manual until you get more comfortable.  Drop the magic _*get/*_set methods.  D2 relies on intercepting the method calls to do it's stuff.  Treat array collections as arrays and build specific methods for interacting with your entities.

Specifically:

```
public function addPageBasket($pageBasket)
{
    $this->pageBaskets[] = $pageBasket;
}
...
$page->addPageBasket($pageBasket);
```

PS. For your particular question, most likely $basket is not an object.

Comment: This doesn't work for me and I don't even use magic get and set methods. I still get the same error